# How to add one value to the next column with if condition?

Tags: arrays, struct

I have a multi dimensional array of structs.
What i want to know is how do i put one value on to the next column if i already know the row.

For example if the value of the row 4 and column 0 is equal to something i want to put that something on to the next column.

Here is what i have:

```
for(j=0; j<numWays;j++){
    if(something){
    ways[getIndex(address)][j+1].tag = zero;
    }
}
```

but it's not working... can somebody help me?

Comment: What is not working about it? Do you get any error messages? It might also help to know what language this is.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (assuming the queried value is not the last object on the row):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array[row].length-1; i++) {
    if (array[row][i] != QUERY) {
        array[row][i+1] = QUERY
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't explained myself very well... I already know the row... i do not need a for() cycle for the rows i only need it for the columns... i want to check the columns and if i find a value and the value is different from my input i want to put the input in to the next column...